# How to describe a type for a Map or object so that it checks that all keys are entered, without Record?

Tags: typescript

Hello) sorry for my English, please tell me how to describe ts type for Map or object so that when filling Map or object to check that all GradeLevel keys are entered? That is, if you forgot [GradeLevel.FIVE, EmojiCode.SMILING_FACE_WITH_HEART_EYES], then ts would swear about it.
I wanted to do it via Record, but it requires GradeLevel keys to be strings, but I don't need it that way.)

```
enum GradeLevel {
  ONE = 1,
  TWO = 2,
  THREE = 3,
  FOUR = 4,
  FIVE = 5
}

const GRADE_EMOJI_MAP = new Map<GradeLevel, EmojiCode>([
  [GradeLevel.ONE, EmojiCode.CONFOUNDED_FACE],
  [GradeLevel.TWO, EmojiCode.SLIGHTLY_FROWNING_FACE],
  [GradeLevel.THREE, EmojiCode.SLIGHTLY_SMILING_FACE],
  [GradeLevel.FOUR, EmojiCode.SMILING_FACE_WITH_SMILING_EYES],
  [GradeLevel.FIVE, EmojiCode.SMILING_FACE_WITH_HEART_EYES]
])

const GRADE_EMOJI_MAP_2 = new Map<GradeLevel, EmojiCode>([ // Error, forget GradeLevel.FIVE
  [GradeLevel.ONE, EmojiCode.CONFOUNDED_FACE],
  [GradeLevel.TWO, EmojiCode.SLIGHTLY_FROWNING_FACE],
  [GradeLevel.THREE, EmojiCode.SLIGHTLY_SMILING_FACE],
  [GradeLevel.FOUR, EmojiCode.SMILING_FACE_WITH_SMILING_EYES],
])
```

Comment: ① Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when others copy and paste it into their own IDEs. Any private or third party things like `EmojiCode` should be declared for us, or even better, replaced with something built-in.  ② You say "or object", so presumably you'd be okay with just a plain object whose keys are `GradeLevel`s?  I'd be happy to show you what that looks like but my IDE is very unhappy about `EmojiCode`, which brings us back to the usefulness of a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I think you can implement this easily using objects instead of Maps, for your example this type should do the work.

```
type GradeLevelMap = {
  [key in GradeLevel]: string;
};
```

Basically it takes every **value** from your enum and makes it a key. Full example below.

```
enum GradeLevel {
  ONE = 1,
  TWO = 2,
  THREE = 3,
  FOUR = 4,
  FIVE = 5,
}

type GradeLevelMap = {
  [key in GradeLevel]: string;
};

const gradeLevelMap1: GradeLevelMap = {
  [GradeLevel.ONE]: 'one',
  [GradeLevel.TWO]: 'two',
  [GradeLevel.THREE]: 'three',
  [GradeLevel.FOUR]: 'four',
  [GradeLevel.FIVE]: 'five',
};

const gradeLevelMap2: GradeLevelMap = {
  1: 'one',
  2: 'two',
  3: 'three',
  4: 'four',
  5: 'five',
};

// const gradeLevelMap3: GradeLevelMap = {
//   1: 'one',
//   2: 'two',
//   3: 'three',
// };
// Type '{ 1: string; 2: string; 3: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'GradeLevelMap': 4, 5
```